# Is there a Latin idiom equivalent to "great minds think alike"?

Tags: idiom

In English we have the idiom [great minds think alike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/great_minds_think_alike), which we usually use when two people coincidentally have the same idea at the same time. It's taken in a jovial manner and not as a serious statement about the minds of both individuals.

Is there a Latin idiom that has the same emphasis and tone? It wouldn't be difficult to simply translate it, but it wouldn't have the context of meaning it has in English.

Comment: Does anyone know if there are standard versions of this saying in other languages? That would provide some pointers as to whether this should be expected to exist in Latin. I can't think of anything in Finnish that parallels that, which I'll take as a weak sign that the English phrase is unlikely to have a Latin origin.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta In French we say "les grands esprits se rencontrent" literally "great minds encounter each other". It's from a letter by Voltaire if I remember correctly